# NSPredicate for multiple objects and properties

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa

I have the following extension method to search in an array:

```
- (NSArray *)searchItemsForTerm:(NSString *)term;
{
    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name contains[c] %@", term];
    return [[self filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate] copy];
}
```

Sometimes not all my objects in the array have the "name" property. In this case I get an exception.
Is there a way to create this predicate which can ignore any non existing properties?

Thanks!

Comment: You could make introspection in your CoreData entities to check if an entity has an attribute... http://oleb.net/blog/2011/05/inspecting-core-data-attributes/

Comment: And if you want to change the property name depending on what entity it is, use `@"%K contains[c] %@", myPropertyName, term];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like:

```
- (NSArray *)searchItemsForTerm:(NSString *)term;
{
    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name contains[c] %@", term];
    NSArray *filteredArray = [self filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
        if ([evaluatedObject respondsToSelector:@selector(name)]) {
            return [resultPredicate evaluateWithObject:evaluatedObject];
        }
        return NO;
    }]];

    return filteredArray;
}
```